# (Solved but need help) What are the units of measurement here?!?

Tags: calculus

The ocean liner Titanic lies under 11000 feet of water at the bottom of the Atlantic Ocean. (The density of water is 62.4 lb/ft^3.)

What is the water pressure at the Titanic? (include units)

686400 lb/ft^2

What is the total force on a circular porthole (window) of diameter 7 feet standing vertically with its center at the depth of the Titanic? (include units)

16826800pi (What are the units here?)

I have tried everything I can think of and it is still incorrect.
I'm absolutely certain the amount is correct but I'm not perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Hint/Suggestion: Here is a trick I learned from basic physics. In your calculations, try to keep track of units in your work and "cancel" them out when needed. For example, let's say I want to convert $k$ minutes into seconds. Then
$$k\text{ min}\times\frac{60\text{ sec}}{1\text{ min}} = 60k\text{ sec}.$$
This is how I would keep track of units.